# Administrator lost privilages on main DC - WindowsServer 2012r2x64

Tags: permissions

I have 1 DC and 1 Domain Admin account on Windows Server 2012 R2. 
The Administrator on DC lost all privileges. If i do remote connection using my Domain Admin account i can push group policies. When i connect with Administrator account on DC and try to push group policies it is giving `Access Denied` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Administrator should be a member of "Domain Admins". Check if all members of Domain Admins have "AdminCount" this identifies them as having AdminSDHolder which resets the permissions on protected groups on a regular interval. All users in Domain Admins should have an AdminCount.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Domain Admins" | Get-ADUser -Properties AdminCount | Select-Object -Property Name,AdminCount
```